# Is it an algebraic set?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose $f\in \mathcal{E}nd(\mathbb{P}^{n}_{\mathbb{C}})$, i.e. $f$ is an endomorphism of the $n$-dimensional complex projective space. Chow's theorem tells us that$f$ is induced by the same degree homogeneous polynomials. We know $f$ is surjective and has finite fibre.

Suppose we have an algebraic set $E \subset \mathbb{P}^{n}_{\mathbb{C}}$ (may not irreducible but we can assume it irreducible for simplicity) and we define a new set $F=\{x\in \mathbb{P}^{n}_{\mathbb{C}}|f^{-1}(x)\subset E \}$. Is it $F$ an algebraic set?

I encounter this question when I study complex dynamics, as I want to construct a totally invariant set under $f$ and I hope it could be an algebraic set.

Does anyone can help me or give me some references about it? Thanks a lot.

Comment: The complement of $F$ is $f({\bf P}^n\backslash E)$, so is the image by $f$ of a Zariski open subset. This is open because $f$ is flat (because $f$ is a finite surjective map between regular schemes). Its complement is thus closed and thus the answer is yes.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is "yes". As we know, if $U$ is a Zariski open set, then $f(U)$  contains a Zarishi open set. Therefore $\overline{f^{-1}(A)}=f^{-1}(\overline{A})$ if we take Zariski closure. Hence, we are done. Here we use the fact $f$ is a projective map hence proper which maps an algebraic set to an algebraic set.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. You're going in the wrong direction compared to your question and ignoring necessary hypotheses.

Comment: Why am I going in the wrong direction? @KReiser

Comment: You're trying to show that the image of a closed set is closed in the question, but here in the answer you're showing that the preimage of a closed set is closed. The latter is trivial since morphisms are continuous, the former requires a result which actually uses the hypotheses here, since it's false in general.

Comment: @KReiser The latter is not trivial, since for a general continuous map we don't have this result. If $f$ is a general continuous map, we only have $\overline{f^{-1}(A)}\subset f^{-1}(\overline{A})$. We have this result because $f$ is a proper map, which maps algebraic set to algebraic set.

Comment: Sorry about that, the closure of the inverse image is not the inverse image of the closure in general. But your justification in the answer doesn't work - consider the endomorphism of $\Bbb A^2$ given by $(x,y)\mapsto (x,xy)$. You have to use properness to get that the image of a closed set is again closed.

Comment: Yeah, but $f$ is a projective map, hence it is proper. @KReiser

Comment: Exactly, and that doesn't appear ***anywhere*** in your original answer! I think this conversation has reached the end of its usefulness, good day.

Comment: @KReiser. I think my comment above (in the main question) shows that the question of the OP has a positive answer iff the morphism is open (the reasoning is purely topological). In the situation of the question, this holds because the morphism is flat.

Comment: Thanks a lot! A flat morphism is an open map, I recall it.  @Damian Rössler

Comment: Hi guy, to be a good mathematician, firstly to be polite, unless you were Faltings. I can rewrite my answers if my writing is not good enough. @KReiser